# How to configure firefox over command line on a linux machine

Tags: firefox, bash, command-line

I use two Internet connections so i want to use bash scripts to automate the task of switching between the two..
the problem is i cant able to configure firefox proxy settings via scripts, so is there a way to do that... does any configuration file exists for firefox so that i can modify over command line..

I have read this entry but this dint helped me much.. (its on windows)
[firefox proxy settings via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843340/firefox-proxy-settings-via-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the "automatic proxy configuration" for this. this field takes a "pac" file which in fact is just a javascript function named `FindProxyForURL` that can use things like `dnsResolve` or `isInNet` to determine wether a proxy is needed or not. there is a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) which describes the files in detail and i have written a [blog post](http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2007/11/03/automatic-proxy-configuration-in-firefox) a while a go that gives an example function.

Comment: hi... thanks for the reply.. i saw that javascript on your blog and i am quite excited wondering how to use it.. i am n00b at this.. if you give me some more hints then it would help me to figure out the solution much quicker... :)

Comment: you could use the myIpAddress function in an if and deside based on the ipadress of your computer which proxy to return