# Change Firefox Proxy from C# code

Tags: c#, firefox, proxy

I have changed IE proxy from my C# code by accessing the Regisrry Settings
so How can I change Mozila Firefox proxy from my C# code?

Comment: from command line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843340/firefox-proxy-settings-via-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the prefs.js in your profile directory. Some sample code can be found here: http://support.mozilla.com/sv-SE/questions/727731
Be sure to close firefox before editing that file!