# How do I concatenate two text files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, merge, text-files, powershell-2.0

I am trying to replicate the functionality of the `cat` command in Unix.

I would like to avoid solutions where I explicitly read both files into variables, concatenate the variables together, and then write out the concatenated variable.

Comment: Closely related question about merging files via a _copy_ operation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71209707/45375

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Simply use the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Content) cmdlets:

```
Get-Content inputFile1.txt, inputFile2.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

You can concatenate more than two files with this style, too.

If the source files are named similarly, you can use wildcards:

```
Get-Content inputFile*.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

**Note 1:** PowerShell 5 and older versions allowed this to be done more concisely using the aliases `cat` and `sc` for `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` respectively. However, these aliases are problematic because `cat` is a system command in *nix systems, and `sc` is a system command in Windows systems - therefore using them is not recommended, and in fact `sc` is no longer even defined as of PowerShell Core (v7). The PowerShell team [recommends against using aliases in general](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5862#issuecomment-357079132).

**Note 2**: Be careful with wildcards - if you try to output to `inputFiles.txt` (or similar that matches the pattern), PowerShell will get into an infinite loop! (I just tested this.)

**Note 3**: Outputting to a file with `>` does not preserve character encoding! This is why using `Set-Content` is recommended.

Comment: Just in case someone wants to iterate over files with the _Get-ChildItems | Foreach-Object_ construct you might want to use Add-Content instead of Set-Content. Otherwise the target file is overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: Note that by default `Set-Content` uses national code page (e.g. Windows-1252 for English). If the source files contain other coding (e.g. Windows-1251 or UTF8), you must set correct encoding `sc file.txt -Encoding UTF8` (numbers such as 1251 for Russian are supported since v6.2)

Comment: @Jonas The problem with `Add-Content` is that if you run the command twice, the aggregated file is twice as long. A good replacement is `Out-File`. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57379958/1152054)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if the files are binary (for example, parts of a zipfile in my case).

Comment: @DanielLidström It also works for binaries with the correct parameters: `Get-Content my.bin -Raw | Set-Content my.bin -NoNewline` will not alter `my.bin` except the timestamps. `-Raw` preserves any CR/LF bytes, while `-NoNewline` prevents PowerShell from adding its own CR/LF bytes.

Comment: how do we do this in alphabetical order? i want to merge files in a specific order

Comment: @Jonas: Instead of using _per-file_ `Add-Content` calls inside a `ForEach-Object` script block, append another pipeline segment that pipes _directly_ to `Set-Content`, which will send all input to a single output file. Not only is this much faster, it avoids the problem of `Add-Content` preserving preexisting content in the output file.

Comment: Smi: _No_ file-writing cmdlets _preserve_ input encoding, because they have no information about it (`Get-Content` reads text into .NET strings without saving information about the original encoding). Thus, in the absence of an explicit `-Encoding` argument, it is a file-writing cmdlet's _own default_ that determines the encoding. `>` is in effect an alias of `Out-File`, which in _Windows PowerShell_ unfortunately defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16). `Set-Content` defaults to the system's legacy ANSI code page, as @RadekPech notes. In PowerShell _Core_ BOM-less UTF-8 is now the consistent default.

Comment: Also, ending up with a different character encoding is not the only potential problem: the _newline format_ (LF vs. CRLF) may change, and a newline will be appended to the content of files that happen to have no trailing newline. However, you can address this in PowerShell v5+ with a combination of `Get-Content -Raw` and `Set-Content -NoNewLine`.

Answer (score 63):

Do not use `>`; it messes up the character encoding. Use:

```
Get-Content files.* | Set-Content newfile.file
```

Comment: `cat` is an alias for `Get-Content`.

Comment: @n0rd I think it was more of a "use the pipeline instead" thing.

Comment: Can confirm. Was getting `ÿþ` which is `FF FE` at the beginning of my concatenated file when using `>`.

Comment: `>` is an effective alias of `Out-File`, which in Windows PowerShell defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE), whereas `Set-Content` defaults to the system's legacy ANSI code page. While the latter encoding is less problematic, note that _both_ cmdlets have the potential to alter the encoding of the input files, because their default encoding is unrelated to the encoding of the input files (which is information that PowerShell doesn't make available). Note that _PowerShell (Core) 7+_ now fortunately defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, consistently across all cmdlets.

Answer (score 26):

In `cmd`, you can do this:

```
copy one.txt+two.txt+three.txt four.txt
```

In PowerShell this would be:

```
cmd /c copy one.txt+two.txt+three.txt four.txt
```

While the PowerShell way would be to use [gc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx), the above will be pretty fast, especially for large files. And it can be used on on non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) files too using the `/B` switch.

Comment: For me the cat command runs multiple orders of magnitude longer than the cmd /c command (which runs really quick); thanks for pointing out the option!

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: You should add `/b` to the target file to prevent byte 0x1A being added to the end of the file: `copy one.txt+two.txt+three.txt four.txt /b`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9699976/11942268).

Answer (score 15):

You could use the [Add-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849859.aspx) cmdlet. Maybe it is a little faster than the other solutions, because I don't retrieve the content of the first file.

```
gc .\file2.txt| Add-Content -Path .\file1.txt
```

Comment: To what does `gc` refer?

Comment: `gc` is an alias for Get-Content

Comment: `gc` (`Get-Content`) _does_ retrieve the file content, line by line by default. Use `Set-Content`, not `Add-Content`, because the latter will preserve any preexisting content in the output file. Note the potential to end up with a different character encoding in the output file (irrespective of what cmdlet you use), as discussed in the comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

To concat files in command prompt it would be

```
type file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > files.txt
```

PowerShell converts the `type` command to `Get-Content`, which means you will get an error when using the `type` command in PowerShell because the `Get-Content` command requires a comma separating the files. The same command in PowerShell would be

```
Get-Content file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt | Set-Content files.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

I used:

```
Get-Content c:\FileToAppend_*.log | Out-File -FilePath C:\DestinationFile.log 
-Encoding ASCII -Append
```

This appended fine. I added the ASCII encoding to remove the nul characters Notepad++ was showing without the explicit encoding.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to order the files by specific parameter (e.g. date time):

```
gci *.log | sort LastWriteTime | % {$(Get-Content $_)} | Set-Content result.log
```

Answer (score 4):

To keep encoding and line endings:

```
Get-Content files.* -Raw | Set-Content newfile.file -NoNewline
```

Note: AFAIR, whose parameters aren't supported by old Powershells (<3? <4?)

Comment: I found that adding `-Encoding unicode` to the end of the command you suggest (in addition to your two parameters) allows Excel to open a combination of CSV files correctly.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.2#parameters for more.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
get-content input_file1 > output_file
get-content input_file2 >> output_file
```

Where `>` is an alias for "out-file", and >> is an alias for "out-file -append".

Answer (score 3):

Since most of the other replies often get the formatting wrong (due to the piping), the safest thing to do is as follows:

```
add-content $YourMasterFile -value (get-content $SomeAdditionalFile)
```

I know you wanted to avoid reading the content of $SomeAdditionalFile into a variable, but in order to save for example your newline formatting i do not think there is proper way to do it without.

A workaround would be to loop through your $SomeAdditionalFile line by line and piping that into your $YourMasterFile. However this is overly resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "powershell way" could be :

```
set-content destination.log -value (get-content c:\FileToAppend_*.log )
```