# Concatenate files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using PowerShell 3.

What is best practice for concatenating files?

```
file1.txt + file2.txt = file3.txt
```

Does PowerShell provide a facility for performing this operation directly? Or do I need each file's contents be loaded into local variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two text files in PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749929/how-do-i-concatenate-two-text-files-in-powershell)

Answer (score 55):

If all the files exist in the same directory and can be matched by a simple pattern, the following code will combine all files into one.

```
Get-Content .\File?.txt | Out-File .\Combined.txt
```

Comment: `Get-Content ... | Out-File ... ` is arguably the clearest expression of *my* intent when I'm doing something like this. It doesn't matter to me whether I can match a simple pattern; there are a lot of ways to select files in PowerShell. The default encoding for Out-File is more often correct for me than the default encoding for Set-Content; Out-File defaults to Unicode, and Set-Content defaults to ASCII.

Comment: For everyone wondering why this fails on Windows 8+, use this instead: `Get-Content .\*.txt | Out-File .\Combined.txt`

Comment: Like @masi says, I was confused by the pattern expression. For everyone as dense as me, the question mark (`?`) only matches one character. Use an asterisk (`*`) if you need to match multiple.

Comment: That produced a recursive file bomb for me, don't put the output file in the same directory as the input files.

Comment: Not very useful because it doesn't show that input files must be separated by commas.

Comment: The outfile will be UTF-16, which doubles the file size

Answer (score 34):

I would go this route:

```
Get-Content file1.txt, file2.txt | Set-Content file3.txt
```

Use the -Encoding parameter on Set-Content if you need something other than ASCII which is the default for Set-Content.

Comment: +1, I always love these simple one's :) Of course, Out-File would be just as good.

Comment: @AthomSfere Yes and if you want Unicode encoding Out-File defaults to that.

Comment: This answer avoids the problem of recursion when `*.txt` is used as input (because set-content locks the file)

Answer (score 8):

If you need more flexibility, you could use something like

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.cs | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ } | Out-File -Path .\all.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Warning: Concatenation using a simple `Get-Content` (whether or not using `-Raw` flag) works for text files; Powershell is too helpful for that:

- Without `-Raw`, it "fixes" (i.e. breaks, pun intended) line breaks, or what Powershell thinks is a line break.
- With `-Raw`, you get a terminating line end (normally CR+LF) at the
  end of each file part, which is added at the end of the pipeline. There's an option for that in newer Powershells' Set-Content.

To concatenate a binary file (that is, an arbitrary file that was split for some reason and needs to be put together again), use either this:

```
Get-Content -Raw file1, file2 | Set-Content -NoNewline destination
```

or something like this:

```
Get-Content file1 -Encoding Byte -Raw | Set-Content destination -Encoding Byte
Get-Content file2 -Encoding Byte -Raw | Add-Content destination -Encoding Byte
```

An alternative is to use the CMD shell and use

```
copy file1 /b + file2 /b + file3 /b + ... destinationfile
```

You must not overwrite any part, that is, use any of the parts as destination. The destination file must be different from any of the parts. Otherwise you're up for a surprise and must find a backup copy of the file part.

Comment: On PowerShell 5, it failed trying to concat together a few 2GB files. But CMD copy worked great!

Answer (score 1):

```
gc file1.txt, file2.txt > output.txt
```

I think this is as short as it gets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to ensure the concatenation is done in a specific order, use the `Sort-Object -Property <Some Name>` argument. For example, concatenate based on the name sorting in an ascending order:

`Get-ChildItem -Path ./* -Include *.txt -Exclude output.txt | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ } | Out-File output.txt`

**IMPORTANT:** `-Exclude` and `Out-File` **MUST** contain the same values, otherwise, it will recursively keep on adding to `output.txt` until your disk is full.

Note that you *must* append a `*` at the end of the `-Path` argument because you are using `-Include`, as mentioned in [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

a generalization based on @Keith answer:

`gc <some regex expression> | sc output`

Comment: while this answer looks like it meant `bash`, the reason for short names are aliases in PowerShell - where `gc` is Get-Content and `sc` is Set-Content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting example of how to make a zip-in-image file based on Powershell 7

```
Get-Content -AsByteStream file1.png, file2.7z | Set-Content -AsByteStream file3.png
Get-Content -AsByteStream file1.png, file2.7z | Add-Content -AsByteStream file3.png
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the examples above worked very well for me because I was dealing with large (5GB+) files.  Set-Content makes it first be all loaded in memory (explodes RAM use) and then write it all.  Instead, a text stream write is better.  I put the below approach to combine a header file and a data file after looking at the answers to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763762/best-way-to-combine-extra-large-text-files)!

```
$file = [system.io.file]::OpenWrite("$($pwd.Path)\out.txt")
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($file)

cat headers.txt,data.txt | ForEach-Object { $writer.WriteLine($_) }

$writer.Close()
$file.Close()
```