# Entity Framework Core - Scaffold existing database to one or group of class files

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, .net-core

As stated in this [tutorial](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model), I can scaffold code-first EF Core from an existing database using `Scaffold-DbContext` in the Package Manager Console.

It's all good but my problem is that it scaffolds separate class files for each table and another for the context class. I find this a bit messy if I have too many tables.

I can rearrange it all by hand but Is there a way to scaffold everything to one class file? Or maybe having the context class on a separate file and then group the tables to another file per schema.

Comment: It's a walk in the park to combine all the class files into one using PowerShell. You'll get duplicate `using` blocks, but these don't cause errors, and you can just remove unused `using` statements with PowerShell or something.  The Power Shell command is: `Get-Content class-files.* | Set-Content combined.file`. From this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16709708/8741

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not an option of EF Core scaffolding as of 1.0.0.