# How to merge multiple text files with 'copy' in Windows Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, merge, copy

I want to merge the content of multiple text files to one text file.

I've tried `cat` explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749929/how-do-i-concatenate-two-text-files-in-powershell). But it is very slow.
The `copy` command is much faster but you have to put the filenames in a plus sign separated string like:

```
cmd /c copy file1.txt + file2.txt + file3.txt + file1.txt all.txt
```

It is ok for a few files, but not for thousands of files.
So my idea was to create a variable that contains the file input for `copy` like:

```
%list = 'file1.txt + file2.txt + file3.txt + file1.txt'
```

and then:

```
cmd /c copy %list all.txt
```

But this doesn't work.

(I can create the string with the filenames also within Powershell with a loop.)

Now I want to make a loop that merges the first file with the second file and the resulting file with the third file and so on.

```
cmd /c copy file1.txt + file2.txt merge1.txt
```

then:

```
cmd /c copy merge1.txt + file3.txt merge2.txt
```

...

How can I do this within a loop in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Forces the creation of your content file
New-Item -ItemType File ".\all.txt" –force

# Build your file list here
$fileList = @('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt')

# Assumes that all files are in the directory where you run the script
# You might have to adapt it to provide full path (e.g. $_.FullName)
$fileList | %{ Get-Content $_ -read 1000 } | Add-Content .\all.txt
```