# How can we use "ls" command for appending file list from FTP to local file?

Tags: powershell, ftp

I'm using the command `ls *Pattern*Date* Files.txt` to get a list of files from FTP to my local text file.

I'm now required to get multiple patterned files (The `Date` and `Pattern` may come in different order). So when I try to add another line `ls *Date*Pattern* Files.txt`, this clears the `FCCfiles.txt` and I'm not able to get the first set of files.

Is there any command that can append the list of files rather than creating new files list?

Comment: Try the Add-Content cmdlet.

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append the listing to a file with `ftp`.

But you can merge multiple listings in PowerShell. I assume that you run `ftp` from PowerShell, based on your use of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) tag.

In `ftp` script do:

```
ls *Pattern*Date* files1.txt
ls *Date*Pattern* files2.txt
```

And then in PowerShell do:

```
Get-Content files1.txt,files2.txt | Set-Content files.txt
```

*(based on [How do I concatenate two text files in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8749929/850848))*