# Copy (append) multiple files into a single destination file

Tags: powershell, cmd, merge, append, copy-item

I'm having a weird issue with using PowerShell to merge multiple csv files into one. I've done this plenty of time in the cmd prompt on in windows 7, but here the output only contains the earliest file. The command is standard stuff:

```
C:\> copy *.csv output.csv
```

All I am getting is, as I say, the earliest csv copied into this new file but nothing else. Is this an issue with powershell vs simple cmd prompt?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: In a PowerShell console, `copy` is an alias for the `Copy-Item` command. The `cmd` `copy` is not the same as `powershell` `Copy-Item`.

Comment: You might try `Get-Content -Path '.\*.csv' >'.\output.csv'`

Comment: @lit There could be a problem, because `Get-Content` finds the `output.csv` too. I suggest: `Get-Content -Path '*.csv' -Exclude 'output.csv' >'output.csv'`

Comment: @zett42, yes, good catch.

Comment: @lit, the problem with a `Get-Content` approach is that you may inadvertently alter the character encoding, newline format and trailing-newline-or-not status (the latter two you can avoid with `Get-Content -Raw` and `Set-Content -NoNewLine`, however).

Answer (score 5):

As noted by [lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit) in the comments, in PowerShell `copy` is a built-in alias of the [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) cmdlet, which functions differently from `cmd.exe`'s internal `copy` command:

- As of PowerShell 7.2.1, **`Copy-Item` does *not* support merging multiple files into a single destination file**. See the bottom section for a - potentially content-modifying - `Get-Content` solution.
- Currently, if `Copy-Item`'s `-Destination` argument (the second positional argument, `output.csv` in your case) is a *file*, all `-Path` arguments (the first positional argument, `*.csv` in your case) are *sequentially* copied *to the same destination file* - in other words: the *last* file that matches wildcard pattern `*.csv` "wins", and `output.csv` is simply a copy of *it alone* - see [GitHub issue #12805](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12805) for a discussion.

---

**To use `cmd.exe`'s `copy` command**, which *merges* the input files to form the destination file, **call via `cmd /c`**:

```sh
cmd /c 'copy /y /b *.csv output.csv'
```

*Caveat*: As discussed in [aschipfl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212351/45375), how a *preexisting* `output.csv` file is handled depends on whether `output.csv` happens to be the *first* file matched by wildcard pattern `*.csv` or not. Either use the workaround proposed there, or simply ensure that no `output.csv` file is present beforehand.

Note the addition of:

- `/y`, which suppresses a confirmation prompt if the destination file already exists
- `/b`, which copies in *binary* mode, which prevents an "EOF character" (the [Substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character), `0x1a`, which you can interactively produce with<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>) from being appended to the destination file.

As an aside: on *Unix-like platforms* you could use `sh -c 'cat *.csv > output.csv'`, but there you'd *always* have to first ensure that there's no preexisting `output.csv` file, as that would result in an endlessly growing file.

---

Alternatively, you **may use the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet to merge multiple text files**, as proposed by lit and refined by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) in the comments on the question, but **doing so can change the character encoding and newline format**, which may or may not be desired in a given use case:

```sh
# !! Caveat: may change character encoding and newline format.
# !! -Encoding utf8 used as an example.
Get-Content *.csv -Exclude output.csv | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 output.csv
```

- `Get-Content`, assuming it interprets a text file's encoding correctly (based on a file's BOM, if present, and assuming a default otherwise), loads a file's lines into .NET strings, and the information about the file's character encoding is *not* preserved.
- Similarly, file-*writing* cmdlets such as [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) (and its effective alias `>`) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) operate on .NET input strings and use a *default* encoding when saving to a file - though a different encoding may be requested via the `-Encoding` parameter.

  - In other words: If your input file had a consistent, non-default encoding that you want to preserve in the destination file, you (a) need to know what that encoding is and (b) request its use via `-Encoding`.
  - Note: *Windows PowerShell* defaults to the system's legacy ANSI code page for `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`, and to UTF-16LE ("Unicode") for `Out-File` / `>`. By contrast, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now commendably uses (BOM-less) UTF-8, consistently across all cmdlets.
- Additionally, because files are read *line by line* by `Get-Content` by default, information about the specific *newline format* is lost. The file-saving cmdlets then use the *platform-native* newline sequence (CRLF (`` "`r`n" ``) on Windows, LF (`` "`n" ``) on Unix-like platforms), so the destination file may end up with a different newline format. Also, the information as to whether a given file had a *trailing* newline is lost.

  - At the expense of having to read each file into memory in full (which normally isn't a problem with text files), you can preserve the original newline format and trailing-newline status by combining `Get-Content -Raw` with `Set-Content -NoNewLine`:

    ```sh
    Get-Content -Raw *.csv -Exclude output.csv | 
      Set-Content -Encoding utf8 -NoNewLine output.csv
    ```

As for **use cases**:

- You can use `Get-Content` + `Set-Content` for one or more of the following scenarios:

  - If your input files are *text* files that use *varying* character encodings (all of which `Get-Content` needs to be able to recognize),  so as to create a consistently encoded destination file.
  - Similarly, even if the input files have the *same* encoding, you can choose to *transcode* the content, i.e. to choose a different encoding for the destination file.
  - If you want to normalize the newline format to the platform-native format and possibly also to ensure the existence of a trailing newline.
- Otherwise, **if the input files' content must be preserved as-is - which is especially true for *binary* files - use the `cmd /c 'copy ...'` approach**.

  - Solving this in PowerShell would require nontrivial use of lower-level .NET APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The [`copy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) of [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) concatenates files when you specify multiple source files and a single destination file just as you do, so the command line:

```cmd
copy *.csv output.csv
```

should concatenate all files matching the source pattern `*.csv` in the order they are reported by the file system (hence in something like alphabetic order on NTFS). You should append the `/B` option at the end to mark the destination file as binary and therefore avoid an end-of-file character (`0x1A`) to become appended.

But as soon as `output.csv` exists, the result depends on the position it is returned by the the search against the source mask `*.csv`:

- `output.csv` is the first item: all the other files become appended to `output.csv`, given that the overwrite prompt is confirmed, or the `/Y` switch is added;
- `output.csv` is not the first one: all the other files become concatenated to `output.csv`, the original `output.csv` file seems to be ignored;

This has been tested on Windows 10, also considering the console output of `copy`, which lists all copied files, but excludes `output.csv` unless it is at the first position.

So to get a result independent from the file system, you could simply explicitly specify the first item (namely `nul`, the null device, providing no data) and use the `+` operator supported by `copy`:

```cmd
copy /Y nul + *.csv output.csv /B
```

This ensures that a potentially already existing file `output.csv` is never the first one in the list of files to become copied and therefore being ignored for concatenation.