# Updating Internet Explorer/Chrome settings via command line

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, proxy, cmd, pac

I've configured my own pac files (containing the proxy server to use and a list of sites/hosts that the proxy bypasses)

It would be too much of a hassle to change all browser settings for different computers manually. Ater doing some research I found that with Firefox you can change proxy settings via command line as the proxy settings are stored in the user's prefs.js file in their Firefox profile. For more info: [firefox proxy settings via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843340/firefox-proxy-settings-via-command-line)

Is it possible to change IE/Chrome proxy settings via command-line, without having to change registries, like with Firefox? Or perhaps changing somekind of .ini file?

Thanks in forward!